# Bash: Compare exit codes of two functions

Tags: bash

Is there an elegant way to compare exit codes of two functions in bash? For example

```
b ()
{
    local r=$(rand -M 2 -s $(( $(date +%s) + $1 )) );
    echo "b$1=$r";
    return $r;
} # just random boolean    
b1 () { b 1; return $?; } # some boolean function
b2 () { b 2; return $?; } # another boolean function ( another seed )
```

I'd like to use something like this

```
if b1 == b2 ; then echo 'then'; else echo 'else'; fi
```

but stuck with this "not xor" implementation

```
if ! b1 && ! b2 || ( b1 && b2 ) ; then echo 'then'; else echo 'else'; fi
```

And speaking more generally, can one compare exit codes of two functions arithmetically and use that comparison in if statement?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you expect this code  `b 1; return $?;` to do?  Since the result of running `b 1` is not saved in a variable, what are you hoping to accomplish by running it?  Separately, what do you expect the value of `$?` to signify?

Comment: I expect b 1; return $?; returns result of b 1, i.e. zero or one, because $? is a variable that stores exit code of last executed command. Yes, i do understand difference between stdout and function result;

Comment: Shell functions don't have return values; they have exit statuses, with well-defined semantics: `0` means success, any other non-zero value means failure.

Comment: Ahhh, i see why this question. It's just a sample. Actually b1 and b2 are some test functions like IsSomeAssertion and IsAnotherAssertion. And i want to know if both of them are false or true at the same time. Just now i end up with this solution: if (( $(b1)$? == $(b2)$?  )) ; then echo 'then'; else echo 'else'; fi but it works only if b1 and b2 don't put anything to stdout.

Comment: @chepner yes, i meant return status. BTW, i never used term "return value"

Comment: You may not have used the term, but that's what you are effectively trying to use by treating the exit status as a boolean value.

Comment: @chepner, and why not to do so? Exit codes are intended to be treated like that, since "if" analyses return status of test command, and this is a valid construction: if ls ; then echo 'then'; else echo 'else'; fi

Comment: `if` assumes that success is 0, not 1. They *are not* Boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare exit codes of `b1` and `b2`:

```
b1; code1=$?
b2; code2=$?
[ "$code1" -eq "$code2" ] && echo "exit codes are equal"
```

In shell, statements like `b1 == b2` cannot stand alone.  They need to be part of a `test` command.  The `test` command is commonly written as `[...]`.
Also, in shell, `=` (or, where supported, `==`) are for string comparison.  `-eq` is for numeric comparison.

Comment: Thank you for good explanation. By the way, as far as i understand, in `(( ))` construction `==` is for numeric comparison.

Comment: Yes, inside `((...))`, `=` is assignment and `==` is a test for equality.  The construct `((...))` offers bash's full arithmetic capabilities.  This, however, can lead to [unpleasant surprises.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172103/security-implications-of-using-unsanitized-data-in-shell-arithmetic-evaluation)  Another difference is `[...]` is POSIX and therefore portable but `((...))` is not.